# a submit input type that interactes with database

Tags: php, html, mysql

how can I with a *input type* submit can increment something or decrement something in a database?

In my case I'm doing an inventory managment tool and in a html table I have a input type that  adds stock and other that removes, how can I connect those buttons with the database?

Answer (score 0):

In the form, use two inputs with the same name but different values.

```
<input type="submit" name="direction" value="+">
<input type="submit" name="direction" value="-">
```

Then in the PHP, check the value of `$_POST['direction']` and use that in the database update.

```
if ($_POST['direction'] == '+') {
    $increment = 1;
} elseif ($_POST['direction'] == '-') {
    $increment = -1;
} else {
    die("Invalid direction");
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE yourTable SET something = something + ? WHERE id = ?")
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $increment, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: when i press to add or remove doesn't do nothing don't know how to solve it but will keep looking on how to, but  thanks for your response!

Comment: Is the button in a form? Submit buttons need a form to submit.

Comment: <td><form method="post"> 
            <input type = "submit" name = "direction" value ="+">
        </form>
        </td>
        <td><form method="post"> 
            <input type = "submit" name = "direction " value ="-">
        </form>

Comment: That should work.